# How to display entire graph using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a json dataset which I loaded, and now I am trying to display it in a bird view. But I want to set the zoom scale initially so that the entire graph is displayed and there is no possibility of zoom or pan, I tried using all kinds of variations of the scale function but nothing seems to work. Can someone give some guidelines on how this can be done using d3? Thanks in advance.

EDIT

HTML:

```
 <div id="birdView" class="center">
      <svg id="bird" width="1000" height="700"></svg>
 </div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    var nodes2 = {
    {% for node in graph.nodes %}
        "node_{{node.identifier}}": { id: "node_{{node.identifier}}", name: "{{node.name}}" },
    {% endfor %}
};

    console.log(nodes2);

    var links2=[
    {% for node in graph.nodes%}
        {% for adjacent_node in node.neighbour_nodes %}
            {% for key,value in graph.get_nodes.items %}
                {%if key == adjacent_node %}{
                    source : "node_{{node.identifier}}",
                    target: "node_{{value.identifier }}"},
                {%endif%}
            {%endfor %}
        {%endfor %}
    {% endfor %}];

    console.log(links2);

    links2.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodes2[link.source]
    link.target = nodes2[link.target]
    });


    //bird view
    var birdForce = d3.layout.force() 
            .size([500, 500])
            .nodes(d3.values(nodes2))
            .links(links2) 
            .on("tick", tickBird) //sta treba da se desi kada su izracunate nove pozicija elemenata
            .linkDistance(100) //razmak izmedju elemenata
            .charge(-100)//koliko da se elementi odbijaju
            .start(); //pokreni izracunavanje pozicija

    var birdSvg = d3.select('#bird');
    // add the links
    var link2 = birdSvg.selectAll('.link2')
         .data(links2)
         .enter().append('line')
         .attr('class', 'link2');

    var node2 = birdSvg.selectAll('.node2')
            .data(birdForce.nodes()) //add
            .enter().append('g')
            .attr('class', 'node2')
            .attr('id', function(d){return d.id + "2";})//da bi id bio jedinstven dodato je +2
            .attr('tekst', function(d){return d.name;});


    d3.selectAll('.node2').each(function(d){birdPrikaz(d);});

     function birdPrikaz(d){
          console.log(d.id);
          //Ubacivanje pravougaonika
          /*d3.select("g#"+d.name+"2").append('rect').
          attr('x',0).attr('y',0).attr('width',100).attr('height',10)
          .attr('fill','yellow');
          //Ubacivanje naziva cvora
          d3.select("g#"+d.id+"2").append('text').attr('x',50).attr('y',10)
          .attr('text-anchor','middle')
          .attr('font-size',textSize).attr('font-family','sans-serif')
          .attr('fill','green').text(d.name);

          //Ubacivanje razdelnika
          d3.select("g#"+d.id+"2").append('line').
          attr('x1',0).attr('y1',10).attr('x2',100).attr('y2',10)
          .attr('stroke','gray').attr('stroke-width',2);*/
          if(d.id == 'node_root') {
                d3.select("g#"+d.id+"2")
                .append('circle')
                .attr('r', 15)
                .style('fill','orange');

                d3.select("g#"+d.id+"2").append('text')
                .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
                .attr('font-size', 12 )
                .style('fill', 'blue')
                .text(function(d){return d.name;});
          } else {
                 d3.select("g#"+d.id+"2")
                 .append('circle')
                 .attr('r', 10)
                 .style('fill','#60e42c');

                  d3.select("g#"+d.id+"2").append('text')
                  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
                  .attr('font-size', 12 )
                  .style('fill', 'red')
                  .text(function(d){return d.name;});
          }
        }

    function tickBird(e) {
            node2.attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";})
                .call(birdForce.drag);
            link2.attr('x1', function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        }
</script>
```

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877019/plot-a-graph-using-d3-js

Comment: Can you post the code that you have written so far?

Comment: Can you also add the relevant html that you are binding to?

Comment: I changed the size in the force layout and it worked for me